# STM32 MEMS microphone - weird output

Tags: stm32, microphone, mems

I have an STM32f407vgt development board that has a MEMS microphone ([MP45DT02](https://www.marutsu.co.jp/contents/shop/marutsu/ds/MP45DT02.pdf)) on it.  I aim to take processable data from this microphone. STM32 provides PDMtoPCM conversion library and I2S peripherals. I have set sampling frequency to 44KHz and used 64 decimation factor to get meaningful data. But the real problem is that microphone output does not change according to sound.

[image: microphone output]

This is the output of microphone. The microphone output frequency is 1.4Mhz. I suspect that the microphone is not responding properly. Is this output is normal or am I doing something wrong?

edit:
This is the clock signal to drive microphone
[image]

Comment: What does your circuit look like?  Are you supplying it with the correct clock signal?

Comment: Really dumb question from me:  You are aware that the microphone outputs digital data, right?

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084-discovery-kit-with-stm32f407vg-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf , in this documentation at page 29 circuit is shown, I am measuring PC3 as it is the output of microphone.

Comment: @JRE Yes, I am aware that it should give pulse density modulated digital signal, not like this weird signal at oscilloscope.

Comment: It would be useful if you could capture both the data and the clock traces on the scope, along with the scale information (v/div, time). Also, are you grounding the scope probe correctly and near the mic IC?

Comment: Are you driving PB10 with an appropriate clock signal?  The microphone needs the clock input.

Comment: Ick.  That circuit is converting the PDM signal to audio with a low pass filter instead of capturing the digital data.

Comment: @JRE I am driving PB10 with 1.4Mhz square signal to trigger microphone and response comes at low clock. So output signal should be different width digital signal right?

Comment: A few things, have you selected the Left or Right channel correctly? Can you show a scope plot of the Clk signal? What Frequency are you clocking at (When you say the microphone output is 1.4MHz is that half the clock speed)? Just to check what does the Vdd look like on the microphone? Also you mean 44.1kHz right not 44kHz thats not a standard audio rate.

Comment: Where did you pick up that signal?  At the input to U7, or the output of U9.

Comment: @JRE from PB10, microphone CLK pin.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first picture.

Comment: @JRE, ohh that is taken from PC3, Microphone DOUT pin, I am actually sorry for not giving all informations on question describe section.

Comment: PC3 also goes to the STM32.  How have you set PC3 on the STM32?  It should be either an input or tri-stated.  Definitely no pull up or pull down.

Comment: Yes, it is driven no-push pull mode. PC3 is set as I2S data input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112013/discussion-between-emre-iris-and-jre).

Comment: I'm out of ideas.

Comment: To verify the hardware, find the original demo binary for the STM32F4 discovery.  I seem to recall that worked, and that other software claiming to interpret the microphone did not, but it's been years since those experiments.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have tried an example audio project provided by ST's itself. That one did not work too, I am convinced the microphone is broken.

Comment: No, not "an example", I specifically mean you should try the exact **binary demo image** that shipped on the STM32F4 discovery.  You'll find it online if you look.  My recollection is that many people (including myself) found that this worked, but that none of those involved in the discussion ever got anything else to work.